# how to combine and sum up the result from two lists based on unique id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have a method which retrives two lists.
and i am showing the list based on union .

but i want to sum the amount based on the unique id which is `FC_Id`

```
public List<ContractFundingCategory> CalculateContractFundingCategoryAmountbyPurchaseOrder(int poId, string serviceType)
{
    List<ContractFundingCategory> lstContractFundingCategory = new List<ContractFundingCategory>();

    var lstContractFundingCategoryEbs = 
        (
            from payment in context.PaymentDetails
            join reimEbs in context.Reimbursement_EBSUtilization on payment.REU_Id equals reimEbs.Id into ebs_join
            from reimEbs in ebs_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join purc in context.PurchaseOrders on payment.PO_Id equals purc.Id
            join serviceDetail in context.fServiceDetails on reimEbs.SD_Id equals serviceDetail.Id
            join fundingCategory in context.fFundingCategories on serviceDetail.FC_Id equals fundingCategory.Id into fundingCategory_Join
            from fundingCategory in fundingCategory_Join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where payment.PO_Id == poId && (serviceDetail.ServiceType == serviceType)
            group new { fundingCategory, payment, serviceDetail } by new
            {
                fundingCategory.Id,
                serviceDetail.ServiceType,
            } into grp
            select new
            {
                FC_Id = grp.Key.Id,
                serviceType = grp.Key.ServiceType,
                BudgetAmount = grp.Sum(p => p.payment.PaymentAmount),
            }
        )
        .AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ContractFundingCategory
        {
            FC_Id = x.FC_Id,
            BudgetAmount = x.BudgetAmount,
            ServiceType = x.serviceType.ToString()
        }).ToList();


    var lstContractFundingCategoryCds = 
        (
            from payment in context.PaymentDetails
            join reimCds in context.Reimbursement_CDSUtilization on payment.RCU_Id equals reimCds.Id into cds_join
            from reimCds in cds_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join cdsutil in context.CDSUtilizations on reimCds.CDSU_Id equals cdsutil.Id
            join purc in context.PurchaseOrders on payment.PO_Id equals purc.Id
            join serviceDetail in context.fServiceDetails on cdsutil.ServiceDetail_Id equals serviceDetail.Id
            join fundingCategory in context.fFundingCategories on serviceDetail.FC_Id equals fundingCategory.Id into fundingCategory_Join
            from fundingCategory in fundingCategory_Join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where payment.PO_Id == poId && (serviceDetail.ServiceType == serviceType)
            group new { fundingCategory, payment, serviceDetail } by new
            {
                fundingCategory.Id,
                serviceDetail.ServiceType,
            } into grp
            select new
            {
                FC_Id = grp.Key.Id,
                serviceType = grp.Key.ServiceType,
                BudgetAmount = grp.Sum(p => p.payment.PaymentAmount),
            }
        )
        .AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ContractFundingCategory
        {
            FC_Id = x.FC_Id,
            BudgetAmount = x.BudgetAmount,
            ServiceType = x.serviceType.ToString()
        }).ToList();

    //lstContractFundingCategory.AddRange(lstContractFundingCategoryEbs);
    //lstContractFundingCategory.AddRange(lstContractFundingCategoryCds);

    //List<ContractFundingCategory> a = new List<ContractFundingCategory>();

    lstContractFundingCategory =  lstContractFundingCategoryEbs
        .Union(lstContractFundingCategoryCds)
        .ToList();

    return lstContractFundingCategory;

}
```

Can any one help me with out writing a loop statement

Comment: As a general comment: Please don't just copy & paste your code into SO. Take your time to indent it nicely and small enough so people don't have to scroll horizontally too much in order to see what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lstContractFundingCategory.Aggregate(new Dictionary<int,int>(), (acc,elem) => { acc.ContainsKey(elem.FC_Id) ? acc[elem.FC_Id] += elem.BudgetAmount : acc.Add(elem.FC_Id, elem.BudgetAmount); return acc; });
```

Aggregate is a fold analogue which iterates your value and applies them to an accumulator. In this case, we're providing a new dictionary as the accumulator. The anonymous function is checking to see if the dictionary has your key; if it does, then it adds the budget value to the current value, and if it doesn't adding the key with the initial budget value. It will return a Dictionary with the keys being your unique FC_Id's and their values being the sum total of those budgets.